# How to customize button of react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to make my application button in `react-native` like below

[image]

I am using inbuilt `Button` view of react native where I see that it does not allow to change the height also. I want to change the height as well rounded like expected image.

This is how my button is looking :

[image]

```
  <Button
    title="CONTINUE"
    color="#FE434C"
    onPress={() => navigate("EnableNotification")}
  />
```

Comment: style={{borderRadius:10}}

Comment: What i usually do is avoid using the button view and use a TouchableOpacity implementation. In your instance id fill it with a red view, then set borderRadius = 15 or so. Interested to see if there is a better way. Try setting style = borderRadius 15 and see if that works

Comment: I have tried `<Button
            title="ENABLE NOTIFICATION"
            color="#FE434C"
            onPress={null}
            style={{ borderRadius: 40 }}
          />` but it not making buttons rounded

Comment: Documentation does not have `borderRadius` attribute https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html

Comment: Try my method @Williams , i can post some code if you want

Comment: @RyanTurnbull Thanks It will work. I do not want to go for this. Is there any library which can help me ? Do you have an idea ? Anyways if you can post snippet of code of it then I may go if it is good to go

Comment: @Williams posted, i'll have a quick look for a library for you though

Comment: @Williams [this](https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button) looks promising

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So this is what I usually do:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {/* do this */}}>
  <View style={{
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      alignItems: 'center', 
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderRadius: 15
    }}
  >
    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Button</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I find using this method makes buttons much more customisable, but if you do some digging there could be a library which implements something similar (I never really found the need to search for it).

NOTE: Obviously you will have to adjust the height/width of the button to your flavor.

EDIT: My mistake... I had put the `onPress` prop in the view, woops.

Comment: I find this is good to go. Thanks :) How to set height here ?

Comment: Do so in the <View style = {{height: ...}}> area. I'd suggest looking into flex-box however, which is great for multiple screen-sizes.

Comment: Now I see click is not working `onPress={() => navigate("EnableNotification")}`

Comment: @Williams im guessing navigate is a function in your component? If so use onPress={() => {this.navigate("EnableNotifcation")}

Comment: I am using react navigation for navigation purpose https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ use what ?

Comment: I tried `onPress={() => {
              this.navigate("EnableNotifcation");
            }}` but it is not working also :(

Comment: Oh no that shouldn't have, since ur using react navigation ( I usually implement it myself :P ) hard to tell without seeing your code/error message. I'd suggest following the tutorial you linked above closely, and ask another question with more details on the mainpage if that doesn't work

Comment: Hmm I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607821/react-native-navigation-is-not-working-on-view lets see

Comment: This is good, except shadows on TouchableOpacity elements don't work on Android. That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Nice solutions. BUT how would you handle "disabled" state?

Comment: @stakantin TouchableOpacity has a `disabled` prop

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to easily style buttons using `TouchableOpacity`, `Text` and `StyleSheet`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

export default class CustomButton extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        /* Custom Button */
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.customBtnBG}
          onPress={() => {}}  >
          <Text style={styles.customBtnText}>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  /* Here, style the text of your button */
    customBtnText: {
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: "#fff",
    },

  /* Here, style the background of your button */
    customBtnBG: {
    backgroundColor: "#007aff",
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 30
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan Turnbull, Well, i think a little padding and fontSize will do.

```html
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onLogin()}>
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderRadius: 15,
      padding: 15,
    }}>
    <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '800'}}>
      Button
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {/* do this */}}>
<View style = {{backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', 
                justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 15}}
       >
    <Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>Button</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

In React-native, we can customise user defined button component and call it from anywhere. So that we can have structured approach throughout the program or application.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from "react-native";

const MyButton = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={props.onPress}
    >
      <View style={{...styles.buttonStyle, ...props.style,
         backgroundColor:props.buttonColor, 
         borderColor:props.buttonColor}}>
        <Text style={{...styles.TextStyle, ...props.style, 
          color:props.fontColor}}>
          {props.children}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  TextStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
export default MyButton;
```

In style `...` spread operator is used to integrate all the styles from same components and incoming styles from parent component through props.

`props.children` is used here to pass button title, so that title text is displayed on the button.

When button is pressed then instead of handling this press event inside of the button but inside of the component where we use this button. So we pass a fitting function reference on the button.

This MyButton button component can be called anywhere inside the program like:

```
<MyButton onPress={() => onPressFunction()}
 buttonColor="red" fontColor="white">Button Title</MyButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touchable Opacity and it's prop border radius to adjust it's curve.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity

Answer (score -2):

You can use this library https://github.com/APSL/react-native-button to create a customizable button in react native.

```
<View>
    <Button
        style={{
            backgroundColor: "#FE434C",
            borderColor: "transparent",
            borderRadius: 20,
            width: 250,
            height: 50,
        }}
        textStyle={{ color: "#FFFFFF" }}
        onPress={() => { }}
    >
        CONTINUE
  </Button>
</View>
```